# Auto following a twitter user

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

```
$follows_faelazo = $twitteroauth->get('friendships/exists', array('user_a' => $_SESSION['username'], 'user_b' => 'faelazo'));
if($follows_faelazo){
    echo 'You are following @faelazo! Proceed to unfollow...';
    $twitteroauth->post('friendships/destroy', array('screen_name' => 'engmohamed_'));
}
```

With this code, I can automatically let a twitter user logged in on my website to follow my account, But how can I follow the twitter user. Like I need to reverse the process so that I can automatically follow the logged in user, Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

`$twitteroauth` is created with your users token/secret, so all actions with `$twitteroauth` are affecting his account.

Just create another `$twitteroauth` object using your token/secret. (you can either get them somewhere in dev.twitter.com  or just use your application yourself and extract them (if you collect them) )